# Are the only people who can work in security those who were learning from 10 years old?

Tags: linux

I'm a second years Master student in computer science. As time passes, the more my desire to work in computer security increases.

I have many friends who are more experienced than I, who told me that I'll not be able to work in this area, because most of the people who are working in this area were learning since they were 10 - 13 years old.

Is it true that you have to be in security when you're still a child if you are going to be in security as an adult?

Comment: This is purely an opinion question. What matters is your interest and your willingness to put in the effort to learn. Your age does not matter.

Comment: Anwer to the title: No. I know living evidence

Comment: Are learning what? General education? That starts usually long before 10 y.o.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is provably nonsense.

There are countless people in security who started at all sorts of ages; some who have had careers in entirely different fields before moving to security.

Sure, it can help in some areas if you have known security concepts for longer, but it's much more important to have an open mind to learning the subject.